# Assembly Geometric Drawing

Tags: assembly, geometry, irvine32

I am working on my project with assembly language I have a text file each line in the text contain 2 coordinates (x1,y1) (x2,y2) and this coordinates is a line i can draw , my task is to find the how many rectangles and how many squares and triangles these coordinates can make , So I have to find 4 intersections and this give me 1 rectangle and by checking the distance I can differentiate between square and rectangle and if i found 3 intersection so its a triangle my main problem is how to find the intersection

I read the text and saved the number in an array of struct of type line this line contain 4 variables which are x1,y1,x2,y2 by using this array of struct how can I find the intersections to find the number of each shape .

the problem here is that on each each line in the text file there exist coordinates of 2 points which makes a line between those 2 points after reading the whole file i would have many lines which i need a sort of condition to check what these multiple lines form as geometrical shape (rectangle-square-triangle).

so i make struct line { x1 byte , y1 byte , x2 byte , y2 byte } and i made an array of line {(20,20,30,50),(10,10,50,50),(10,10,30,50),(20,20,40,20),(40,20,30,50),(40,20,40,60),(40,60,100,60),(100,50,105,50),(100,60,100,20),(100,20,40,20)} and this is the values of the coordinates ...what is the conditions to detect the result shapes from this intercepted line?

Comment: Solve the math first, then ask about assembly. It's not clear what precisely you want, what accuracy, etc... drawing lines on screen will make them alias to pixels, so they are no more lines, and intersections on pixel boundaries are not true analytical intersections, and this whole task being solved in pixel/integer world smells "inaccuracy and bogus results" far away, so you should probably solve it without pixels, just in pure analytical geometry. And to design such algorithm with reasonable performance, you will probably have to use advanced graph theory (doesn't look trivial to me).

Comment: then there are questions like what should for example: 5 5 95 5, 5 5 5 95, 95 95 95 5, 95 95 5 95, 50 0 50 100 produce (it's one square [5,5 -> 95,95] halved into two by line through middle)... one square + two rectangles? Or only two rectangles, because square is cut? Etc... you have lot of work (math) to do before any programming...